# autotools: avoid shipping source generator

Tags: autotools, automake

In my project i use a source generator. Now for the make dist target i don't want the end user to require the generator, so i decided to add pregenerated source files to the tarball by using

```
EXTRA_DIST = generated.cc
```

Unfortunately the Makefile in the creates tarball also contains the rule to generate generated.cc

```
generated.cc : input.txt
          scarygenerator input.txt > $(top_builddir)/generated.cc
```

As input.txt is not part of the tarball this rule is executed and fails.

It it possible that "make dist" omits this rule when generating the Makefile for the tarball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autotools are designed to make compliance with the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) easier (e.g. the corresponding source, which in this case might include `input.txt` and `scarygenerator`).  However, since your project may not be bound by GPL restrictions, you can do this to *not* include `index.txt` in the tarball:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for source generation])
AS_IF([test -f index.txt], [gen_source=yes], [gen_source=no])
AC_MSG_RESULT($gen_source)
AM_CONDITIONAL([GEN_SOURCE], [test x$gen_source = xyes])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = ... generated.cc

if GEN_SOURCE

generated.cc : index.txt
    scarygenerator $< > $@
endif
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a simple solution, i just don't get why you added nodist_data_DATA

Comment: It could work without `nodist_data_DATA`.  I just put it there to make sure it explicitly doesn't get distributed.

Comment: It does work without `nodist_data_DATA`. I removed it because `index.txt` could be installed by `make install` when `index.txt` is present, and I assume that's not what you want.